# React native app cant execute from emulator in android studio due that compile error

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

Script 'C:\codecanyon-PR4cUUls-antiqueruby-react-native\Ecommerce Material-UI\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 232

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

Script 'C:\codecanyon-PR4cUUls-antiqueruby-react-native\Ecommerce Material-UI\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 232

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

```
at makeError (C:\codecanyon-PR4cUUls-antiqueruby-react-native\Ecommerce Material-UI\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)    
at C:\codecanyon-PR4cUUls-antiqueruby-react-native\Ecommerce Material-UI\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\codecanyon-PR4cUUls-antiqueruby-react-native\Ecommerce Material-UI\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\codecanyon-PR4cUUls-antiqueruby-react-native\Ecommerce Material-UI\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Command-Line Interface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peQF4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYZBg.png)

I need to solve that issue. I changed my gradle version also but it does not work. I tried everything I had apply. please help me to solve that.

Comment: I could use an answer for this too.